# Remove first characters from a list

Tags: python

I'm working on a program to have a user input what they want for dinner and then output a shopping list. Currently user can enter which meals they want and it will print out the list sorted in order from produce, meat, and other.

I want the program to output the material without the category number in front and with a line break after each entry but I've had some problems dealing with lists instead of strings. So far I've tried a regex to replace numbers with nothing or substituting the numbers with spaces.

Bonus points if someone knows a way to enter in nachos twice and print out 2xchicken instead of chicken twice.

```
enter code here

strog = ["3 egg noddles", "3 beef broth", "2 steak"]
c_soup = ["2 bone in chicken", "1 carrots", "1 celery", "1 onion", "1     parsley"]
t_soup = ["3 tomato saucex2", "3 tomato paste", "1 celery"]
nachos = ["3 chips", "3 salsa", "3 black olives", "2 chicken", "3 cheese"]
grocery = []
done = []
food = ""
while food != done:
    food = input("Please enter what you would like to eat. Enter done when finished: ")
    grocery += (food)
grocery.sort()
print(grocery)
```

Comment: `while food != done:` will never be true

Comment: `split` is the method you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of Lists, try looking at dictionaries.

Comment: Instead of using regexes, given your inputs above, I'd suggest splitting your input, and if the first string from the split operation is a number, then treat it as such.

Comment: No need for regex, just use normal string manipulation.

Comment: Can you post how would like the output to be on console?

Comment: The output I was looking for would be:                                                                 chicken                                 
chicken           
black olives
black olives
cheese
cheese
chips
chips
salsa
salsa                                                                                                      RPGillespie gave me a good way to achieving that. Although the duplicates are a bit annoying if like in the example I input nachos twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some other issues, but you can use (for example) `strog[0][2:]` to get one item in strog or the entire list by doing `new_strog = [x[2:] for x in strog]` to parse out the category number and space.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to learn normal python [string manipulation](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings) and list<->string conversion (`split` and `join`).

Try something like this:

```
strog = ["3 egg noddles", "3 beef broth", "2 steak"]

for ingredient in strog:
    print(" ".join(ingredient.split()[1:]))
```

Or un-uglified:

```
strog = ["3 egg noddles", "3 beef broth", "2 steak"]

for ingredient in strog:
    pieces_list = ingredient.split()
    food_list = pieces_list[1:]
    ingredient_without_number = " ".join(food_list)
    print(ingredient_without_number)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! And yep, looks like I need to learn a few more of the basics. This practice has already taught me a decent amount.